# Let S = {1, 2, 3, 4}. How many equivalence relation are there and describe them?

Tags: equivalence-relations

> **Question**
>
> Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.
>
> How many equivalence relation are there and describe them?

I know that 1~2 and 2~3. I also know that there are 2 equivalence relation but how do I prove that and describe them properly.

Comment: $=$ is an equivalence relation. And you have the trivial "everything is related to everything" relation. That's 2. However, there are more.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalence relations correspond to the partitions of the set and are counted by the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).